# Add Dollar Sign after path in prompt .zsh

Tags: zsh, prompt

I want to add the dollar sign after the path in my prompt.

Current prompt is:

```
.oh-my-zsh git:(master)
```

Wanted prompt is:

```
.oh-my-zsh git:(master) $
```

I tried to modify `PROMPT` in `~/.zshrc` without success.

Comment: Simply append `$` to the `PROMPT`: `PROMPT="<whatever> $"`

Comment: what is <whatever> ? I want to keep path with git.

Comment: Presumably you would put the entirety of your old prompt in place of `<whatever>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/c78277fd8bda5fec87504469afdf121355876006/themes/gozilla.zsh-theme#L1

`PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ %{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%}$ % %{$reset_color%}'`

Answer (score 2):

One way to set the user|superuser character in the prompt, according to the manual, is to add this pattern `%(!.<superuser_char>.<ordinary_user_char>)`. For instance to have this `joe@mypc:~ $` when joe is running the shell as an ordinary user and this `root@mypc:~#` when running as a superuser, *while keeping the user's environment* (i.e. not the `root` environment, for instance when starting a superuser tmux session with `sudo -E tmux new -s admintasks`), this is what should be in `.zshrc`.

```
`PS1='%n@%m:%~%(!.#.$) `
```

See `man zshmisc`, under **SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES / Shell state** section.

Comment: The switch applies when running `sudo zsh` too, so looks like a good substitute for bash's `\$` to me.

Answer (score 1):

editing your PROMPT variable is fine, but maybe you just want to change zsh's behaviour for all prompt themes without going in and modifying every single
`%#` in your themes.
`%` is hardcoded in the source code. but it's pretty simple to edit.
You can find the line in question in the `prompt.c` file in the source code ([github](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/prompt.c)) specifically on line 734 currently.
The code in question is:

```C
        case '#': 
        addbufspc(1);
        *bv->bp++ = privasserted() ? '#' : '%';
        break;
```

All you have to do is change  `%` for whatever character you want, probably `$`, build the program and replace your zsh install.
That might be a pain tho. You can also patch your current binary to replace whatever character you want.
You just have to change a single byte, from 0x25 (%) to 0x24 ($).
The problem is, it's hard to find where that is in your zsh binary!
in my case (Ubuntu 20.04, zsh 5.8) I found this:

```
   $ objdump -D zsh  | less

   8af87:       e8 84 e4 01 00          callq  a9410 <privasserted@@Base>
   8af8c:       4c 8b 2d fd 49 05 00    mov    0x549fd(%rip),%r13        # df990 <keyboardhackchar@@Base+0x210>
   8af93:       0f b6 74 24 10          movzbl 0x10(%rsp),%esi
   8af98:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
   8af9a:       b8 25 00 00 00          mov    $0x25,%eax
   8af9f:       0f 44 f0                cmove  %eax,%esi
   8afa2:       49 8b 45 18             mov    0x18(%r13),%rax
   8afa6:       48 8d 50 01             lea    0x1(%rax),%rdx
```

To be frank im not even sure what most of the instructions here do, but it's easy to see that  instruction at `0x8af9a` is the culprit. Using a Hex editor  (ghex) I replaced the 0x25 there with a 0x24, and now zsh shows a $ prompt!
This is easier than downloading the zsh source and recompiling it, but it took me a while to find the right instruction to patch.  There doesn't seem to be many instances of `privasserted` calls in the binary, so you can probably check all of those one by one and see which one fits.

Hope that was helpful! I am a bash user and that `%` was annoying me too much, so much I refused to try zsh. Now I might give it a try.

Comment: `%` annoys me too.